# How do we keep TurtleBot cables tidy?

Tags: ros, hardware, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We've been playing around with some TurtleBots at the office and occasionally run into issues with dangling wires and blocked indicator lights. I've posted what we've done below - does anyone have other suggestions?

Four pieces of tape (all visible below) keep the cables clean, the Kinect and Create lights visible, and allows enough slack for the netbook to sit on top of the robot or on the lower shelf.
[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10946/how-do-we-keep-turtlebot-cables-tidy?/) by [Ryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/195/ryan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3248 on 2011-08-18

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We've found these [downward right angle adapters](http://www.angledcables.com/usb-20-extension-cable-down-angled-a-si.html) useful.

[Right Angle Usb Adapter (Downward) http://ep.yimg.com/ca/I/yhst-19158458583166_2160_17974016](http://ep.yimg.com/ca/I/yhst-19158458583166_2160_17974016)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-08-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

typically we don't place the laptop on the top deck, our main method of interacting with the robot is through ssh. But if I do put the laptop in the top deck I turn it sideways so the 2 USB ports are at the back with all the cables tucked in the bottom.

---

Originally posted by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) with karma: 8372 on 2011-08-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1